# Converting time from DB to custom time fails

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need to read dates from a db, convert it to a certain timestamp and convert it to JSON.

I have the following code:

```
package usages

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type SpecialOffer struct {
    PublishedDate   jsonTime    `gorm:"column:publishing_date" json:"published_date"`
    ExpirationDate  jsonTime    `gorm:"column:expiration_date" json:"expiration_date"`
}

type jsonTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (tt jsonTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    jsonTime := fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", tt.Format("20060102"))
    return []byte(jsonTime), nil
}
```

When I run it like this I get the following error:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 8, name "publishing_date": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type time.Time into type *usages.trvTime
```

And the data is wrong:

```
{"published_date":"00010101","expiration_date":"00010101"}
```

If I change the `SpecialOffer` struct to use `time.Time`, it return correct, but obviously the format is wrong:

```
{"published_date":"2020-03-12T00:00:00Z","expiration_date":"2020-06-12T00:00:00Z"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should implement the [`sql.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) and [`driver.Valuer`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) interfaces.

Something like this:

```
func (j *jsonTime) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    if t, ok := src.(time.Time); ok {
        j.Time = t
    }
    return nil
}

func (j jsonTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return j.Time, nil
}
```

---

This is necessary because the `database/sql` package which is used by `gorm` and some other go ORMs, if not all of them, provides out-of-the-box support for only a handful of types.

Most of the supported types are the language's *basic* builtin types like `string`, `int`, `bool`, etc. by extension it also supports any custom user defined type whose *underlying* type is one of the aforementioned basic types, then there's supports for the `[]byte` type and the related `sql.RawBytes` type, and lastly the `time.Time` type is also supported ootb.

Any other type that you may want to write to or read from the database will need to implement the two interfaces above. The `sql.Scanner`'s `Scan` method is invoked automatically *after* a column's value is decoded into one of the supported types (that's why you need to type assert against `time.Time` rather than against, say `[]byte`). The `driver.Valuer`'s `Value` method is invoked automatically *before* the *driver* encodes it into a format that's valid for the target column (that's why you can return `time.Time` directly rather than having the do the encoding yourself).

And keep in mind that

```
type jsonTime struct {
    time.Time
}
```

or even

```
type jsonTime time.Time
```

declares a *new* type that *is not equal* to `time.Time` and that is why it's not picked up by the `database/sql` package.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Can you perhaps explain why this is needed? It works, but being extremely new to Golang, I would like to understand why.

Comment: @Albert I've added some context that might help you understand the reasons a bit better, I hope.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate the effort!

Comment: @mkopriva Is it possible to support all custom type whose underlying type is `time.Time`  Like basic builtin types?

Comment: @Eklavya *no* it's not possible. The basic builtin types are "special" in the sense that they have an equivalent representation in the `reflect` package (used by `database/sql`) which are the various constants of the `reflect.Kind` type that can be used to figure out the underlying type. For example `string` has kind `reflect.String`, and `type MyString string` also has kind `reflect.String` etc.

Comment: @Eklavya But `time.Time` has kind `reflect.Struct` and while `type MyTime time.Time` also has kind `reflect.Struct` so does `http.ServeMux` for example, or `type ThisIsNotATimeStamp struct{}` also has a `reflect.Struct` kind, so with non-basic types the reliance on `reflect.Kind` becomes ineffective.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks, that makes sense.